# Why does cannonical implementation of overloading binary arithmatic operator in C++ pass first arguement by value?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

According to [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), passing the first argument of an overloaded binary operator by value somehow optimizes expressions like `a + b + c`. The relevant code snippet from the linked page is as follows:

```cpp
class X
{
 public:
  X& operator+=(const X& rhs)         // compound assignment (does not need to be a member,
  {                                   // but often is, to modify the private members)
    /* addition of rhs to *this takes place here */
    return *this;                     // return the result by reference
  }

  // friends defined inside class body are inline and are hidden from non-ADL lookup
  friend X operator+(X lhs,           // passing lhs by value helps optimize chained a+b+c
                     const X& rhs)    // otherwise, both parameters may be const references
  {
    lhs += rhs;                       // reuse compound assignment
    return lhs;                       // return the result by value (uses move constructor)
  }
};
```

I have 2 questions regarding this:

1. How are chained `a + b + c` expressions optimized by this?
2. Assuming `X` also overrides the copy and move assignment operators and constructors, would a statement like `x = a + b` produce any copying? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether this had that example-writer in mind, but have some explanation. Consider what happens in this code:

```
X a, b, c;
X d = a + b + c;
```

Here, first, `a + b` is evaluated basically as `operator+(operator+(a, b), c)`. Note that `operator+(a, b)` is an *rvalue*, and therefore, `lhs` can, in the outer application of `operator+`, be initialized by *move-constructor*.

An alternative how to implement `operator+` in terms of `operator+=` is as follows:

```
friend X operator+(const X& lhs, const X& rhs) 
{    
   X temp(lhs);
   temp += rhs;
   return temp;
}
```

Note that you need to create a temporary since you need an object to apply `operator+=` on. With this solution, both applications of `operator+` in `operator+(operator+(a, b), c)` involves *copy-constructor*.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/5Dq7jF

Of course, you can add a second version for *rvalues* as follows:

```
friend X operator+(X&& lhs, const X& rhs) 
{    
   lhs += rhs;
   return std::move(lhs);
}
```

But this requires much more typing than the original value-passing version.

---

Generally, passing by value is frequently used in situations where you want to unify overloads for lvalues and rvalues; for example, look for *unified assignment operator*.

Comment: However, if we use the value-passing version on a statement like `X a, b; X c = a + b`, a call to the copy constructor does occur right? For example in the code linked above the output `CMM5` indicates a call to the copy constructor occurs to copy the the value of `a` into the argument of `operator+` when `operator+(a, b)` is evaluated, right?

Comment: @Diggs I believe so. There must be a copy somewhere. You cannot implement that only with moves, when both operands are lvalues.

Comment: @Diggs You may be also interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62179683/580083). I created a separate one, since it deals with a related-but-different problem (in one case, there are two overloads of `operator+` — one for lvalues and one for rvalues).