# Canonical implementation of operator+ involves additional move constructor

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Motivated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62177743/580083), I compared two different versions of an implementation of a binary `operator+` in terms of `operator+=`. Consider we are inside the definition of class `X`.

**Version 1**

```
friend X operator+(X lhs, const X& rhs)   
{
   lhs += rhs;  
   return lhs; 
}
```

**Version 2**

```
friend X operator+(const X& lhs, const X& rhs) 
{    
   X temp(lhs);
   temp += rhs;
   return temp;
}

friend X operator+(X&& lhs, const X& rhs) 
{    
   lhs += rhs;
   return std::move(lhs);
}
```

Where, in both cases, `operator+=` is defined as follows:

```
X& operator+=(const X& rhs)    
{                             
  ... // whatever to add contents of X
  return *this;   
}
```

Now, I just run the following code and tracked calls of copy/move constructors:

```
X a, b, c;
X d = a + b + c;
```

With the first *"canonical"* version, there were 1 copy + **2 move** constructor calls, while with the second version there were just 1 copy + **1 move** constructor calls (tested with GCC 10 and `-O3`).

Question: **What hinders the elision of that additional move constructor call in the first case?**

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/GWEnHJ

---

*Additional observation*: In the live demo, where the class has some contents (integer member variable), the move constructor calls *are not/are* inlined with the *first/second* version, *respectively*. Also, with the second version, the final result 6 is calculated at compile time and hard-coded into the assembly (when passed to `operator<<`), while with the first version, it is read from memory. <s>Generally, the second version seems to be (relatively) much more efficient.</s> But this was likely caused by those `cout` messages involved. Without them, the assembly output was exactly the same.

Comment: Per my previous remark, this does remove all the moves for me. https://godbolt.org/z/8LL4u4 
To me, this suggests what what i put as my answer is what is going on...

Comment: @Taekahn But this solution completely bypasses `operator+` for `X`. Instead, it converts `X` object into `int`, adds there, and converts back to `X`. Simple demonstration: make the `int`-converting constructor and `int`-cast operator `explicit`. Then, the code won't compile.

Comment: @Taekahn Moreover, though your solution is related, my question is not how to avoid constructor calls. I asked why the elision did not take place in the described case.

Comment: The "canonical" version is so-called because it's simple and safe, not necessarily optimal.  Copy-and-swap assignment operators have a similar situation, i.e. copy-and-swap is simple and safe, but less optimal than defining different overloads for value categories like you have done

Comment: @M.M I can undestand this. I would just like to know which language rules hinder the elision in this case.

Comment: Yeah. There is some good reason why a function parameter can't be elided into a return value object but I can't recall it right now . Maybe to do with ABIs and how the caller has to construct the parameter in the calling context and at that point they can't see the function body so they can't know whether or not it's safe to construct the parameter in the return value

Comment: @DanielLangr I can't believe I missed the [tag:language-lawyer] tag before, but I've now added the relevant paragraph. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, I am quite busy now but will check your answer in few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What hinders the elision of that additional move constructor call in the first case?

The defect report [DR1148](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1148) that was accepted and included in C++11.

In short, it says (*emphasis mine*):

> It is unclear whether copy elision is permitted when returning a parameter of class type. If not, it should still be possible to move, rather than copy, the return value.
>
> Suggested resolution: Amend paragraph 34 **to explicitly exclude function parameters from copy elision**. Amend paragraph 35 to include function parameters as eligible for move-construction.

The result can be found in
[[class.copy.elision]/1.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#1.1) (*emphasis mine*)

> in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the *expression* is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration (**other than a function parameter** or a variable introduced by the *exception-declaration* of a *handler* (`[except.handle]`)) with the same type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the object directly into the function call's return object